# Calculate rotation of rect angle by new position and distortion?

Tags: c#, math, 3d, rotation, 2d

I have a game project which is based on augmented reality but I don't want to use any of these library's and plugins out there because they can't do what I want to do after this...etc..

So my question is it is possible to calculate **the rotation of a 2D rect in a 3D world?** If yes how? If no what should I do?

Illustration images for what I'm thinking of:

**The 0 rotation on every axis (x,y,z axis in 2 dimension??)**

[image: The 0 rotation on every axis (x,y,z axis in 2 dimension??)]

**The 0 rotation in the 3D world**

[image: The 0 rotation in the 3D world]

Some rotation in 2D world (which is in 3D --> x70, y10, z30)

**rotation 70,10,30 in 2D**

[image: The rotated rect in 2D]

**rotation 70,10,30 in 3D**

[image]

**So how to calculate the 3D rotation from 2D? Like the AR Games do. How they do this?**

Comment: Depends on which reference orientation you are referring to, i.e. the rotation from *position*? e.g X-Y plane? axis aligned?

Comment: The rotation from the position.

Comment: No I mean from *what* initial position and orientation?

Comment: The initial position variable.. the first known position of it (the 2D object/rectangle). And the initial rotation of the 2D object is 0 on every axis. And the analytical view is top.

Comment: (analytical view = the 2D coordinate system view)

Comment: By "top" I assume you mean looking down along the Z-axis? And that the rectangle is axis-aligned in the X-Y plane?

Comment: Yeah exactly.  Sorry for my bad introduction to my problem. My eglish is not the best :\

Comment: It's OK. I'm just making sure that I have the correct information before I post an answer

Comment: Okay. Many many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an important pre-requisite, you must know *which* edges on the unrotated rect correspond to which ones on the rotated one.

1. Calculate the normals of each rect (A and B) respectively, and compute the *quaternion* required to rotate from A to B => **Q**. (This is probably available in Eigen or another game math library)
2. Calculate the following:

   - The midpoint of the top edge of the unrotated rect => **C**
   - The corresponding point on the rotated rect => **D**
   - The center of the rotated rect => **E**
3. Rotate vector **C** by **Q** to obtain a vector **F**. Rotation by quaternion is another common operation available in most 3D math libraries.
4. Calculate the quaternion to rotate from **F** to **D - E** => **P**
5. Calculate the *final* quaternion **R** = **P * Q**, and convert to axis-angles if you like: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_Angles_Conversion)

Comment: All right thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try next day. (In Hungary there is 0:57 am :) sleep mode)